# I want to get a current frequency with Web audio API

Tags: audio, real-time, frequency

I don't need Visualization, just want to get real current numbers of the frequency, but with `getFloatFrequencyData(freqDomain)` I will get a array. How can I get just one exactly changeful frequency from real time? So here I use the `freqDomain[1]` as the value of the frequency, but the value is wrong. It's always about -100. I think our tone should be min. 250 Hz. Someone can help me?

This is my code：

```
 MicrophoneSample.prototype.visualize = function() {
  this.canvas.width = this.WIDTH;
  this.canvas.height = this.HEIGHT;
  var drawContext = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

  var freqDomain = new Float32Array(this.analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  this.analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(freqDomain);

  var f = Math.round(freqDomain[1]);
   
    var text = f + ' Hz';
    document.getElementById('frequency').innerHTML = text ;

  requestAnimFrame(this.visualize.bind(this));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of rudimentary technique only ever works on artificial signals.  It will fail dismally on any kind of real-word audio signal, and particularly with one produced by just about any kind of musical instrument relying on a vibrating column of air or string - or the human voice.

By using the STFT, you can get far better resolution than the centre frequency of each bin by computing phase difference at each bin from the bin in a previous FFT.  This hinges on the relationship

```
F = dPhi/dt
```

Or in other words, that frequency is the rate of change of phase.

However, you will require a 2048-point FFT to get decent resolution at below 100Hz.

Answer (score 3):

The array has an amplitude for each FFT bin. Since the second bin is -100, I'm guessing these values are in dB (20*log10(x)). To find the dominant frequency, you'll need to search the array for the largest value and then convert its bin number into a frequency.
The first bin is going to be at DC, the second Fs/N and then so on. For example, if your sample rate is 48kHz and your FFT is 1024, then the frequencies are as follows:

```
0: 0 * 48000/1024 = 0Hz
1: 1 * 48000/1024 = 46.85Hz
```

and so on.

The resolution of your frequency meter is going to be limited by the size of the FFT.